# Is it possible to search in MYSQL for a date string?

Tags: mysql

In my wordpress db, I have many posts that start with a date consitantly in the format F j, Y. I want to get rid of these since the information is already in it's own date column. Can I search for all dates in this format and replace them?

Comment: please provide some sample date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This updates all posts where `post_content` starts with the `post_date` formatted as `F j, Y`:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET    post_content = SUBSTRING(post_content FROM 2+CHAR_LENGTH(
                        DATE_FORMAT(post_date, '%M %e, %Y')
                      ))
WHERE  post_content LIKE CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(post_date, '%M %e, %Y'), '%')
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e52b6/1/0).

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like

```
select id,column from table where column regexp '(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}'
```

to find the posts, then remove the date part from the post and re-update the column